# Extract just the repeated field elements from protobuf

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

```
syntax = "proto3";

package TestServer;

service RelaySrv{
    rpc UpdateGroupDetails (Group) returns (Response);
}

message Person
{
    int64 id = 1;
    string name = 2;
}

message Group{

    repeated Person persons = 1;
}

Go code:
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    m := jsonpb.Marshaler{}
    err := m.Marshal(&buf, Group)
```

After doing a marshal on group protobuf message buf variable will have:

{ "persons" : [{"id":"1","name":"sun"},
{"id":"2","name":"sam"}] }

How do I extract just

[{"id":"1","name":"sun"},
{"id":"2","name":"sam"}]

from buf without emptying it??

Comment: What do you mean by "extract"? You are encoding the protobuf message of type `Group` to json. The reader should decode into a "Group" message and then just access the `persons` property.

Comment: I am unmarshalling it to Group using `json.Unmarshal(buf.Bytes(), &Group)` and then extract the part I want and then convert it back to byte[] using  

`b, err := json.Marshal(met)` and then try to ingest to kusto azure-kusto-go like this

`if err := in.Stream(ctx, b, ingest.JSON, "Mapping");`

but it fails

: The input stream is empty after processing, tip:check stream validity"

I tried to create new buffer `z := bytes.NewBuffer(b)` and pass it to ingest and I still get same error

Comment: try `m.Marshal(&buf, Group.Persons)`?

Comment: @zzn it does let me do that, says Persons is not a field or method, it has []Persons but couldn't use that either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there is a better way but instead of marshal into json struct, it worked with encode/decode to json. The ingest.stream doesn't complain anymore and I can see the data in azure-data-explorer

```
    //have a json struct for Group and Person to match the protbuf message posted in the question
    var g Group
    json.NewDecoder(&buf).Decode(&g)

    var b bytes.Buffer
    for i := 0; i < len(g.Persons); i++ {
        e := json.NewEncoder(&b).Encode(&g.Persons[i])

        if e != nil {
            panic("issue marshalling protobuf")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand u correctly, this is what you want.

```
    const b = `[{"id":1,"Name":"sun"}, {"id":2,"Name":"sam"}]`

    persons := []*pb.Person{}

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(b), &persons)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    log.Println(persons)
    // 2021/03/06 22:34:15 [id:1 name:"sun"  id:2 name:"sam" ]
```